# Update multiple users

Tags: powershell

I am trying to simultaneously update some users in my AD, but not being able to generate the script correctly. I am working with .csv and I get errors!

script

```
Import-Csv -Path C:\Temp\userteste3.csv | foreach-Object {Set-ADUser -Identity $_.SamAccountName -Add @{-telephoneNumber $_.telephoneNumber;-OtherPhone $_.OtherPhone;ipPhone $_.ipPhone}}
```

csv

[image]

error

> ```
> No linha:1 caractere:105
> + ... oreach-Object {Set-ADUser -Identity $_.SamAccountName -Add @{-telepho ...
> +                                                                  ~
> O literal de hash estava incompleto.
> No linha:1 caractere:186
> + ... ber $_.telephoneNumber;-OtherPhone $_.OtherPhone;ipPhone $_.ipPhone}}
> +                                                                         ~
> Token '}' inesperado na expressão ou instrução.
>     + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : IncompleteHashLiteral
> ```

Comment: Fix the inline hashtables: `@{-telephoneNumber $_.telephoneNumber;-OtherPhone $_.OtherPhone;ipPhone $_.ipPhone}` -> `@{telephoneNumber=$_.telephoneNumber;OtherPhone=$_.OtherPhone;ipPhone=$_.ipPhone}`

Comment: And to be clear on what Mathias is telling you to do, the dashes (-) in front of your property names shouldn't be there and you need an assignment operator (=) for prop=value in your Add{}.  Add, Replace, Update, etc. on the AD cmdlets expect hashtables and thus, you need to structure them as such.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thx, work fine.